# Is there a virtual file>scan WIA driver?

Tags: wia

We have a third party piece of software with a document library. The only way to get documents in the library is to scan them in. You click the scan button and it pops up with the native windows scanner selection dialog.
This means documents have to be printed out and then scanned!
Unfortunately we can't change the software to get it to ask for a file instead.
Is there a piece of software that looks like a WIA scanner but which when selected gives a 'choose document' option whereby we can point it to the document?
I've tried UniTWAIN however that does not work for us as the software is looking for WIA scanners.

Thanks!